# RTSP Streams Often Fail with 404 on DESCRIBE method

Tags: nest-device-access

Stream URLs generated by the API frequently fail with a 404 code when a client tries to execute the DESCRIBE method.  The behaviour is random even for the same stream url over time.  Below is an example of calling ffprobe on an RTSPS stream URL returned from the API.  Each request is made approximately one second apart after receiving the URL. Again, **this is the same URL each time**. The results are

1. DESCRIBE returns 404
2. DESCRIBE returns 404
3. success
4. success but with empty response
5. success

This would seem to indicate it is not a fault with ffprobe/ffplay/ffmpeg but some kind of issue with the API, perhaps the streams aren't actually ready when the API returns the URL?

````
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[rtsp @ 0x7faa72808e00] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found
rtsps://<stream url>: Server returned 404 Not Found
user@user ~ % ffprobe "rtsps://<stream url>"
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[rtsp @ 0x7fe75b009400] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found
rtsps://<stream url>: Server returned 404 Not Found
user@user ~ % ffprobe "rtsps://<stream urll>"
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsps://<stream url>':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDM
  Duration: N/A, start: -2.877000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
user@user ~ % ffprobe "<stream url>"
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, rtsp, from <stream url>':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDM
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
user@user ~ % ffprobe "<stream url>"
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsps://<stream url>':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDM
  Duration: N/A, start: -1.903000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
user@user ~ % ```
````

Comment: Just a ping to let Google know this is still happening.

Comment: Does the RTSPS URL actually work for live streaming?  Or does it have the same 404 behavior you see with DESCRIBE, and eventually work?

Comment: @BTGunner: It will eventually work if you keep trying in most cases.  However each attempt takes some time, so you could be waiting a long time to view the stream.

Comment: Just a ping to let Google know this is still happening.

Comment: Wow. i just came across this because i'm having the same issue. Nice to know that i'm not the only one having the issue.

Comment: Same problem here, but still no solution in sight?

Comment: Just a ping to let Google know this is still happening.